# Congelar relógio do Windows

Tags: python, windows, time

Seria possível congelar o relógio do Windows com Python?

Se sim, qual a biblioteca faz isso?

Comment: Você poderia detalhar melhor a sua pergunta?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Congelar? Você precisaria ficar voltando 1s a cada segundo rodado. É isso que você quer?

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser que eu não tenha entendido o que você deseja, mas pelo que entendi, não é possível. Nenhum linguagem de programação com biblioteca alguma tem capacidade de fazer uma mudança tão profunda no sistema operacional. Você só pode alterar algo nele se ele permitir, esta é uma das razões para existir um sistema operacional.

Não imagino uma utilidade prática para isto mas é possível obter um resultado próximo disto alterando sucessivamente o horário do computador. Isto o Windows permite. Você poderia criar um laço (o que não permitira a aplicação fazer outras tarefas, embora tenha como permitir isto) para repetir a mudança:

```
import datetime
import time 
time_tuple = time.localtime(time.time())
while True:
    win_set_time(time_tuple)
    time.sleep(1) # espera 1 segundo

def win_set_time(time_tuple):
    import pywin32
    dayOfWeek = datetime.datetime(time_tuple).isocalendar()[2]
    pywin32.SetSystemTime(time_tuple[:2] + (dayOfWeek,) + time_tuple[2:])
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/IO/FreezeClock.py).

Código retirado [dessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292874/221800).